# How to check in loop whether test function applies to array index value

Tags: javascript, html, function, loops, if-statement

I have an array stored in the local storage, I fetch it on browser load and this is what I do when I fetch it:

The way this code supposed to work is if the index fetched has the speciation applied to it then it will be treated as a link, if not it will be treated as a text. I used the same method for the input value and it worked but can't seem to get it to work here:

```
if (leadsFromStorage) {
  //^leads from storage isnt empty
  myLeads = leadsFromStorage;
  console.log(myLeads)
  let listItems = "";
  listItems = document.createElement("li")
  for (i = 0; i < myLeads.length; i++) {
    if (test(myLeads[i]) === true)
    {
      listItems.innerHTML = `
        <li>
          <a target='_blank' href='${myLeads}'>
              ${myLeads}
          </a>
        </li>
        `;
      listEl.appendChild(listItems)
    }
    else {
      listItems.innerHTML = `
            <li>
            
                  ${myLeads}
              
            </li>
            `;
      listEl.appendChild(listItems)
    }
  }
  console.log("storage isnt empty");
}
```

this is the test function

```
function test(input) {
  const expression = /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
  const regex = new RegExp(expression);
  if (input.match(regex)) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

[I want it to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spmus.jpg):

[image]

[but instead it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLQmk.jpg):

[image]

Any help please?

Comment: Can you add an example of the content you retrieve from the `leadsFromStorage` variable?

Comment: (2) ["mark", "Facebook.com"]
0: "mark"
1: "Facebook.com"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(2)

Comment: this is directly from the console log after I asked it to log out the myLeads variable after I set it to equal LeadsFromStorage variable

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, just changed some syntax issues.

```
        function test(input) {
  const expression =
    /[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi;
  const regex = new RegExp(expression);
  if (input.match(regex)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

if (leadsFromStorage) {
  //^leads from storage isnt empty
  myLeads = leadsFromStorage;
  console.log(myLeads);
  let listItems = "";
  listItems = document.createElement("li");

  myLeads.forEach((lead) => { // Use forEach  
    if (test(lead)) { // lead returns true, so if true:
      listItems.innerHTML = `
        <li>
          <a target='_bl>
              ${lead}
          </a>
        </li>
        `;
      listEl.appendChild(listItems);
    } else { // else do: 
      listItems.innerHTML = `
        <li>
        
              ${lead}
          
        </li>
        `;
      listEl.appendChild(listItems);
    }
  });
  console.log("storage isnt empty");
}
```

To fully address the issue I would need all the code.

Comment: "*[I] just changed some syntax issues.*" - which ones? Why? What was the problem? Please: *explain* your answer so that the OP - and others, in future - might *learn* from you.

Comment: sadly this didnt work out for me. the issue here is that i dont know how many elements will be in the leadFromStorage array   now it just puts out the element in the last index